# Swift UIImageView not shown on device

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I'm using following code to display an UIImageView in textFieldDidEndEditing:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableViewBodydata.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! tvcell_Logbook
cell.imageViewArrow.isHidden = false
cell.imageViewArrow.image = UIImage(named: "same.png")
```

The code works perfectly on the iPhone X Simulator. But if im testing it on my iPhone X Device, the imageView isn't shown. The function is called correctly, I debuged it, but nothing happens. I reinstalled the App several times and also restarted the Device but nothing changed. Can anybody help me please?

**Edit 1**

I'm using this code in cellForRow:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: tvcell_Logbook!

    if indexPath.row == 0 {

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellWeight", for: indexPath) as! tvcell_Logbook
        cell.imageViewArrow.isHidden = false
        cell.imageViewArrow.image = UIImage(named: "same.png")
    }

    ...

    return cell }
```

And this code in textFieldDidEndEditing:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableViewBodydata.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! tvcell_Logbook
cell.imageViewArrow.isHidden = false
cell.imageViewArrow.image = UIImage(named: "same.png") }
```

Comment: Suggest opening the Xcode view debugger after the function is run to check if the image view is being positioned properly.

Comment: I checked it, the view is positioned correctly

Comment: Have you given image with all 3 resolution? 1x 2x 3x

Comment: Can you provide the whole code. Where are you writing this code. In cellForRowAtIndexPath ??

Comment: Does `UIImage(named: "same.png")` return a non-nil value on the device? Filenames are case sensitive on real devices.

Comment: Thanks maddy, you were right ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filename is Same.png:

```
UIImage(named: "Same.png")
```

How is your picture named at filesystem?